# What is the use of shortcut "Super key(windows key) + S"?

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys

Recently I was trying to save my work using "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> `+ S`", but I accidentally pressed the

`Super key`(<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>) `+ S`"

and everything appeared to be wrapped inside a solid border yellow line except the left panel.

It looked like this

[image]

I searched for the use of this shortcut but couldn't find anything.

I am new to ubuntu. Please help if anyone knows the use of this shortcut

Comment: If you press and holds the Super key for several seconds, you will get the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shortcut shows all your workspaces. But you first have to enable then in the **System Settings** > **Appearance** > **Behavior** > *Enable workspaces*.
Then you will have 4 workspaces and Super+S will show them and allows you to switch from one to another.

Note that you will also have the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to switch from one to another